# An estimate on the trace norm of a product of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, trace, compact-operators, holder-inequality

I am having some troubles understanding the following paper of Demuth, Stollmann, Stolz and Van Casteren that improves the Hölder inequality for the trace norm : https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01197534

Theorem 1 in this paper gives an estimate of the trace norm of a product of two kernel operators $ \boldsymbol{A}, \boldsymbol{B} $ with respective kernels $ A, B $ acting on the space $ L^2 \equiv L^2(X, \mathfrak{U}, m) $. The theorem states that if $ A(x, \cdot) $ and $ B(\cdot, x) \in L^2 $ for a.e. $x$, and if $ \int_X \vert\!\vert A(x, \cdot)\vert\!\vert_{L^2} \vert\!\vert B(\cdot, x)\vert\!\vert_{L^2} dm(x) < \infty $, then, there exists a trace class operator $ \boldsymbol{A B} $ with kernel given by the usual composition $ (x, y) \mapsto \int_X A(x, t) B(t, y) dm(t) $ such that

$$ \vert\!\vert  \boldsymbol{A B}  \vert\!\vert_{tr} \leq \int_X \vert\!\vert A(x, \cdot)\vert\!\vert_{L^2} \vert\!\vert B(\cdot, x)\vert\!\vert_{L^2} dm(x)  $$

The proof then proceeds to show that the product $ \boldsymbol{A B} $ can be turned into a product of two Hilbert-Schmidt operators (which is fine for me), and does not prove the estimate, which certainly implies that it is trivial. Nevertheless, I don't really know how to start. The several definitions and characterisations of the trace norm $  \vert\!\vert  \boldsymbol{A }  \vert\!\vert_{tr} := \mathrm{tr}( \sqrt{ \boldsymbol{A}^* \boldsymbol{A} } ) $ do not show any integral formula for such a norm (unless I missed this point). The trace is of course given by $ \mathrm{tr}( \boldsymbol{A}) = \int_X A(x, x) dm(x) $, but this does not imply anything on the trace norm, as far as I know.

Any help is welcome to understand how they get their estimate.

Comment: The inequality makes impression of the integral version of the triangle inequality for the trace norm. For fixed $a,b\in L^2$ the trace norm of the (one-dimensional)  operator $f\mapsto \langle f,a\rangle b$ on the space $L^2$ is equal $\|a\|_2\|b\|_2.$ In your case the operator is an  integral of one-dimensional operators with respect to the measure $m$ on the space $X.$

Comment: Yes, there is a remark just after the theorem about that. There is maybe a proof with a spectral decomposition using such one dimensional operators. But I like very much the proof of Martin Argerami that uses the polar decomposition. :)

Comment: @Synia sorry for the random remark but I was wondering if you could provide some elucidation on the notation $A(., x)$. Even after looking at the paper that you referenced I still am unsure what this is supposed to be. Does $\| A(x, . )\|_{L^{2}}$ mean that we take the $L^{2}$ norm over one of the variables of the kernel of $A$ and leave the other so that in the end what we have is a function of $x$? Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Yes, exactly : this is the $ L^2 $ norm over one variable of the kernel $A$ of the operator $ \boldsymbol{A} $ (hence the different notation in my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the polar decomposition, there exists a partial isometry $V$ such that $|AB|=VAB$. Then, using Cauchy-Schwarz and the fact that
$$
VA\xi=V\,\int_X\xi(x)\,A(\cdot,x)\,dm(x)=\int_X\xi(x)\,VA(\cdot,x)\,dm(x)
$$
due to the continuity of $V$,
\begin{align}
\|AB\|_{\rm tr}
&=\operatorname{Tr}(VAB)
=\int_X(VAB)(x,x)\,dm(x)\\[0.3cm]
&=\int_X\int_X(VA)(x,y)B(y,x)\,dm(y)\,dm(x)\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\int_X\|VA(x,\cdot)\|_2\,\|B(\cdot,x)\|_2\,dm(x)\\[0.3cm]
&\leq\int_X\|A(x,\cdot)\|_2\,\|B(\cdot,x)\|_2\,dm(x).\\[0.3cm]
\end{align}

Comment: Very nice ! I had forgotten the polar decomposition. Just to know, (since you are an "Operator Algebraist") are you aware of any finer estimates one can obtain in this way ? The two inequalities used in this proof are very optimal, but maybe this partial isometry approach is used elsewhere in the theory. Very nice in any case.

Comment: That question is very open and I'm not particularly well-versed on inequalities:)

Comment: Well, then, I'm fine with this one :) Thanks.